# How can I enable logging in dalekjs?

Tags: testing, logging, console, dalekjs

I've been doing a simple test in DalekJS and when I try to log.message a string it doesn't show anything in the console. The test succeeds, but there is no message.

Do I have to do anything to enable logging? Or was it supposed to be on by default?

Thank you!

Comment: I found how to show the log.message in your console. I thought it was enabled by default, but you have to use logLevel 4 to see any message.

dalek [your_test].js -l 4

Comment: Yep. That is the reason, would you mind getting this in as an issue over at the DalekJS repo in GitHub?! https://github.com/dalekjs/dalek/issues?state=open

This needs to be documented. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To add an, more or less, official answer.
Your custom logs are only outputted to the terminal if you set your log level >= 4, like so:

```
dalek [your_test].js -l 4
```